# Button command being called automatically

Tags: python, tkinter

For some reason, this Button is automatically calling `bot_analysis_frame` without the button being pressed. I'm guessing it's because the `command` is a function with arguments.

Is there a way to have the button only call this function and pass the required variables *only* upon being pressed?

```
Button(topAnalysisFrame, text='OK', command=bot_analysis_frame(eventConditionL, eventBreakL)).pack(side=LEFT)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Button parameter “command” executed when declared?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-button-parameter-command-executed-when-declared)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Read the section here on passing [callbacks](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-callbacks.htm).

You are storing the result of that function to the command argument and not the function itself.

I believe this:

```
command = lambda: bot_analysis_frame(eventConditionL,eventBreakL)
```

might work for you.

Comment: Note that closures created in a loop will not work as "expected" (it actually works correctly, yu just have to get that closures really capture variables, not values). All the functions created in `[lambda: print(i) for i in range(5)]` will print the final value of `i`, 4. You can hack around this by default arguments, which are bound at definition time: `lambda i=i: print(i)` will work.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this has been answered before. Instead of this:

```
Button(topAnalysisFrame,
       text='OK',
       command=bot_analysis_frame(eventConditionL,eventBreakL)).pack(side=LEFT)
```

You could use lambda like so:

```
Button(topAnalysisFrame,
       text="OK",
       command=lambda: bot_analysis_frame(eventConditionL, eventBreakL)).pack(side=LEFT)
```